# When applying automatic weights to my armature, it goes really small

Tags: armature

I can create my rig fine, but when I apply with automatic weights, the armature goes really small. please see picture.

[image]

Any ideas? Scale is all set to 1

Comment: Can you share more details regarding your scene and/or share your .blend file on blendexchange?

Comment: maybe unparent the object before parenting?

Comment: You’re not supposed to “apply” anything. Also, you are parenting the mesh to the armature, and not the other way round?